# Should the [blocked] tag on MSE be eliminated?

Tags: discussion, meta, retag-request, burninate-request

I just noticed that there's a tag on MSE called [blocked](/questions/tagged/blocked) that's currently on 36 questions. It has no tag wiki/excerpt, and the name is unhelpfully generic/vague as well. As such, it seems like this tag shouldn't stick around in its current form.

At a glance, it looks like most of the posts that currently have this tag are about a variety of different things:

- question/answer bans – those questions should probably have the
  [post-ban](/questions/tagged/post-ban) tag instead
- IP address bans – should have the [ip-ban](/questions/tagged/ip-ban) tag instead
- SE sites being blocked by ISPs/security tools/etc. – not sure if
  there's a tag for these types of questions
- maybe a question or two about blocked text/user input – should have
  the [blocklist](/questions/tagged/blocklist) tag instead
- assorted other topics...?

In general, it doesn't seem like there's a benefit to keeping the [blocked](/questions/tagged/blocked) tag around in its current state. There is not one existing tag it completely matches/overlaps with, so it can't simply be merged into another tag. As such, it seems like each question would need to be manually retagged (at least, until the only questions remaining with the tag fit the scope of an existing tag, at which point it could be merged with that one).

This is too big a project to undertake myself, and I'm not entirely sure what should be done with some of the questions. As such, this seems like something the community should handle collectively.

**Should the [blocked](/questions/tagged/blocked) tag on MSE be eliminated?**

Comment: (I was initially tempted to use the title "Should [blocked] be blocked?", but that would imply that the tag itself should be blocklisted, which doesn't seem necessary in this case.)

Comment: I've seen this tag before and been pretty unhappy with its usage. Kudos for putting up this question, I think it should go. We have other, better tags for what it's currently used for.

Comment: Burn it with fire. It's used quite inappropriately, better tags already exist. Only 36 questions in existence, are you sure you need help?

Comment: possible title would be like, "Do we want to be un[blocked]?"

Comment: punny burnination titles should really be a requirement on non-MSO posts too :) Also, congrats on getting the CV/RV privilege on MSE, @V2Blast! Also - agreed on burninating the tag to hell.

Comment: @Oleg what is a "CV/RV privilege"?

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar close / reopen votes privilege shortened, sorry :)

Comment: @Oleg hehe well he got bit more than that, he's working for SE now and has all the moderator privileges, and some more. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar true that, just congratulated on reaching the threshold naturally :)

Comment: The remaining 17 questions are all in one group - SE is fully or partially blocked for some reason, @V2Blast. The burnination process can thus be finished by simply renaming the tag to something less ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

**It definitely should be**

I just went through the [list of the questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blocked) with the tag (18 done, 18 to go at the time of this writing) and cleaned up a little.

The only viable use of the tag seems to be questions about sites of the network being blocked by some entity indeed, however, we can retag the rest of the posts and come up with a less ambiguous tag name and explicit excerpt / wiki when it comes to that (not sure about the exact name, maybe [se-inaccessible](/questions/tagged/se-inaccessible)? Semantically, something like that should cover cases when parts of the network are made inaccessible due to various reasons).

Comment: Will you please stop flooding the homepage with all your edits

Comment: @Luuklag it was a low activity time, and I am already done - those edits are far from being tag-only.

Comment: That makes it extra problematic. Your edits covered the entire front page for users who set their list to 15 questions. I'm not saying they were bad edits, but common decency dictates you spread these not that useful edits out over a period of time. Not that useful because they were mostly old and closed posts.